# Splicing lists within a list

Tags: python, list, splice

What's the most concise way to return every fourth number in the sublists, treating all the number lists as one list?

```
A = [ ['a',[1,2,3]], ['b',[4,5]], ['c',[6,7,8,9,10]] ]
```

I want the result to look like this, when printing list A:

```
[ ['a',[1]], ['b',[5]], ['c',[9]] ]
```

I can see how this is similar to splicing a single list, in which I'd use something like [::4]. I'm guessing I have to use that here along with something else, treating the number lists as one list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.count()`, which is a handy generator which returns increasing numbers.  Using that, it's almost the same as the question you originally asked, still using a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count()
>>> B = [[let, [n for n in nums if next(c) % 4 == 0]] for let, nums in A]
>>> B
[['a', [1]], ['b', [5]], ['c', [9]]]
```

which works because the first time `next(c)` is called, it gives 0, 0 % 4 == 0 so we keep `n`, the next time we get 1 so we don't keep it, etc.

---

[Answer to original question about removing even elements:]

You can nest list comprehensions:

```
>>> A = [['a',[1,2,3]], ['b',[4,5]], ['c',[6,7,8,9,10]]]
>>> B = [[letter, [n for n in nums if n % 2 != 0]] for letter, nums in A]
>>> B
[['a', [1, 3]], ['b', [5]], ['c', [7, 9]]]
```

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I'm looking for! However, I was getting at how I would phrase the list comprehension if I wanted not just every odd number, but even every fourth number for example, which would result in: [ ['a',[1]], ['b',[5]], ['c',[9]] ].

Comment: However, I now realize I phrased the question poorly with regard to my intent! Hopefully you're still willing to help me resolve it in the comments here, or should I edit my original question wording?

Comment: Original question edited, sorry for the trouble! Should be much clearer now.

Answer (score -1):

You could do a list comprehension! list = [x[::2] for x in A]

Something a little closer to what you wrote would be:

```
list =[[x[0], x[1][::2]] for x in a]
```

Comment: Hmm, that only returns [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]. Furthermore, I tried [x[1][::2] for x in A], but predictably it returned [[1, 3], [4], [6, 8, 10]] which is not what I want. I want the splicing to treat the number lists as one list when splicing.

Comment: Oh, you want the even numbers, not the even number indices. I see

Comment: The other answer should be what you want.  I was a little confused when you gave the [::2] as I assumed that's what you wanted.